# Physics research topic for Undergraduate students

Tags: education, big-list

Can You tell me some research topics for 1st year undergraduate students? I am not getting how to make a research paper?

Comment: Thermo-nuclear astrophysics

Answer (score 1):

A good thing to do is to talk to professors in your department and see what ideas they have for projects since most undergraduate projects I've heard of involve professor mentorship.

Other than that, your question as it stands now is way too broad to produce any good answers.  There is a humongous breadth and depth of potential research projects to get involved in with physics.  You need to provide more specific ideas of what you are looking for in a research project to get more specific answers.  Is there a particular topic you enjoy studying in physics?  Do you want to work in a lab, with simulations, or solving equations?  How long do you want the project to last?